# C++ Operator overloading class object for 2 separate class members

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

Lets say I have a class

```
class Car
{
public:
...
friend operator<(const Car&car1, const Car&car2){
   return car1.getYear() < car2.getYear()
}
private:
   int year;
   double price;
   string brand;
};
```

How can I overload the same operator if I want to compare the Car based on the price? I have to create two Car objects and for the first car object I want to compare using year, for the 2nd car object I want to compare using its price.

Thanks!

Comment: How will the compiler know what you mean when for two arbitrary cars, `c1` and `c2` you do `if(c1 < c2) ...`?

Comment: Presumably you have some methods that do something with the price (otherwise why have it) - what are they? In other words post more, real code.

Comment: The names will be the same in main. I was also thinking that for the other operator overload I can do c2 compared with c1

Comment: @NeilButterworth It just has getters and setters. This class will be inserted in a BST. But when inserting to a BST, i want to be able to compare using year, and then price - separately

Comment: Same problem, Gus. Overload resolution cares nothing for the order of the operands, just the type. if both operands are cars, the overload will be look the same and be ambiguous to the compiler.

Comment: @user4581301 sorry I'm a newbie who's trying to learn, I am not sure what that means. So this is impossible?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. `operator<(const car & car1, const car & car2)` looks identical to `operator<(const car & car2, const car & car1)`

Comment: @Gus it is, your comparison is trivial anyhoo so it'd be better to have an external comparison. I mean would you really expect `Car1 < Car2` to return based only on the `year` property?

Comment: Compilers and Ambiguity: Give a Robot of a choice to pick something out of a Red Bag but you are holding a red bad each in both hands. Without any random chance of picking one or the other or by you specifying to it to choose the left or right hand; the two red bags look identical to the Robot; he doesn't know which one to choose from.

Answer (score 0):

If your class has a getter for price, then you do not need to write an overloaded operator. You can simply say:

```
  Car c1, c2;
  // stuff
  if ( c1.Price() < c2.Price() ) {
       // do something
  }
```

Similarly, you probably didn't need to write the overload in your original post; you could have used a getter. Note I'm not saying getters are great ideas.

Comment: The thing is I am putting this into a templated BST. For it to work, I need to overload them

Comment: @Gus No you don't - you need to provide the tree with a functor that does the comparison.

Comment: I am not sure if I am allowed to use functors since I have not covered that in my class yet

Comment: If your class is covering templates, but not functors, get your money back.

Comment: functors are covered on the next class sequence after this one!

Answer (score 0):

> How can I overload the same operator if I want to compare the Car based on the price?

It will be better to avoid that approach. Instead, use two different functor classes. Let the calling code choose which functor they want to use.

```
struct CompareByYear
{
   bool operator()(Car const& car1, Car const& car2)
   {
      return (car1.getYear() < car2.getYear());
   }
};

struct CompareByPrice
{
   bool operator()(Car const& car1, Car const& car2)
   {
      return (car1.getPrice() < car2.getPrice());
   }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach may appear to be odd at first but it is very simple to follow & implement especially if have you multiple ways to compare a class's internal data type members.

```
class Car {
public:
    enum Comparetor {
        BY_YEAR = 0,
        BY_PRICE = 1,
    };

private:    
    int   _year;
    float _price;
    std::string _make;

public:
    Car() :
        _year( 0 ),
        _price( 0 ),
        _make( "" ) 
    {}
    Car( int year, float price, const std::string& make ) :
        _year( year ),
        _price( price ),
        _make( make ) 
    {}

    int yearOf() const {
        return _year;
    }

    float priceOf() const {
        return _price;
    }

    std::string makeOf() const {
        return _make;
    }

    bool compareByLT( Car::Comparetor comp, Car& car2 ) {
        switch ( comp ) {
            case BY_YEAR: {
                return _year < car2._year;
                break;
            }
            case BY_PRICE: {
                return _price < car2._price;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};   

int main() {    
    Car car1( 2017, 24785.0f, "Ford Mustang" );
    Car car2( 2018, 21579.0f, "Hyundai Elantra" );

    if ( car1.compareByLT( Car::BY_YEAR, car2 ) ) {
        std::cout << car1.makeOf() << " is older than " << car2.makeOf()
            << " by " << car2.yearOf() - car1.yearOf() << " year" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << car2.makeOf() << " is older than " << car1.makeOf()
            << " by " << car1.yearOf() - car1.yearOf() << " year" << std::endl;
    }

    if ( car1.compareByLT( Car::BY_PRICE, car2 ) ) {
        std::cout << car1.makeOf() << " is cheaper than " << car2.makeOf()
            << " by $" << car2.priceOf() - car1.priceOf() << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << car2.makeOf() << " is cheaper than " << car1.makeOf()
            << " by $" << car1.priceOf() - car2.priceOf() << std::endl;
    }

    _getch(); // #include <conio.h> prevent debugging console on Windows in Visual Studio from closing.
    return 0;
}
```

The approach you are trying to do won't work because of ambiguity. Meaning how can the compiler resolve which `overload` to use if you try to define 2 different operators that takes the same 2 same objects meaning their declarations/definitions/signatures are exactly the same. It wouldn't know how to differentiate between which one you meant. Should I compare by `price` or `year`...? And the operators can not accept another parameter to know which one.

If for some reason the code base you have requires that you must define the operator because of some kind of inheritance or data structure mechanics... Then you can overload the operator for only 1 of those values (member types). You will have to choose which one to use that makes the most sense. Then for the other data you would have to write functions or methods to do that. What I have simply shown here is that you can sum up all the comparisons of a class's internal data into a single function that the caller has to pass what enumeration type to compare by.

Or as others have stated; if you have access methods to retrieve the private members than you can simply just do comparison by them if they are built in types or are types that already have the operators defined for them.

A follow up of the current class above: okay so we now have a compare function that compares by less than and we now want to do the same for greater than. Instead of writing the greater than version out completely just as we did before you can simplify the 2nd method like this:

```
 bool compareByGT( Car::Comparetor comp, Car& car2 ) {
     return !( compareByLT( comp, car2 ) );
 }
```

Which saves a lot of unnecessary typing of code minimizing mistakes; however your first function has to be 100% bug free for this 2nd function to be accurate and reliable.

---

Now if you tried to do this: define the `operator<()` for the class itself and define a friend version outside of class as well like this:

```
{
    // Internal: Belongs to class
    bool operator<( const Car& other ) {
        _year < other._year;
    }

    // Friend of this class
    friend bool operator<( const Car& car1, const Car& car2 );
};

bool operator<( const Car& car1, const Car2& car2 ) {
    return car1._price < car2.price;
}
```

What do you think will happen?

Well it is quite simple when you use the compare operator as such:

```
if ( car1 < car2 ) {
    // Do something...
} else { 
    // Do something else...
}
```

It is going to resolve to using the one that belongs to the class.

Now if you comment out the one that belongs to the class keeping the same if statement that is somewhere else in code, the code will not break and when you compile, build and run it again through the debugger it should execute without problem however in this time it will compare by the friend version.